# Get highest count of items from multiple arrays in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

Let's say I have multiple non-numerical arrays in PowerShell:

```
$a = (a, b, c, d)             # $a.count equals 4 items
$b = (e, f, g, h, i, j)       # $b.count equals 6 items, which is the highest count of items in one of the arrays
$c = (k, l, m, n, o)          # $c.count equals 5 items
$d = (p, q)                   # $d.count equals 2 items
...
```

After declaring all those arrays, I would like to get the highest number of counts from all of them, which in the case above would be a count of 6 from array $b.
Is there an easy way to achieve this, instead of comparing each array against the next one and check if the count is higher than before?

Comment: Do you want to get only the highest count? or the array is also needed `$b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [*`Measure-Object`* Cmdlet with *`-Property`* and *`-Maximum`* Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-7.1). The *`-Property`* parameter allows you to measure based on the property value(In this case it's based on the array *`Count`* property)

```
$a = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
$b = ('e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j')
$measureInfo = ($a, $b) | Measure-Object -Property Count -Maximum
Write-Output $measureInfo.Maximum # This will print 6
```

Note that this will print only the maximum *`Count`*. If you want the array also, you probably have to apply a filter based on this value.

```
$MaxArray = ($a, $b) | Where-Object {$_.Count -eq $maximumCount.Maximum}
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution was correct and exactly what I was looking for.